# Why "List<? super Integer> myList" as an argument in a method can accept an ArrayList<Number> numberList = new ArrayList<>();

Tags: java, wildcard, lower-bound

While I was experimenting with Upper Bounded and Lower Bounded wildcards I found the following code snippet.

```
    static void numsUpTo(Integer num, List<? super Integer> output) {
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, num)
            .forEach(output::add);
}

    ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Number> numberList = new ArrayList<>();

    numsUpTo(5, integerList);
    numsUpTo(5, numberList);
```

I do not understand why

```
List<? super Integer>
```

accepts an

```
ArrayList<Number>
```

as an argument.

Since Number is the superclass for Integer and not Integer for Number I would expect to see an error.

Comment: What part don't you understand, specifically? `ArrayList` is a `List`, so no problem there, and `Number` is a superclass of Integer (as is Object), so no problem there, either. You probably want to give https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java a read-over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<? super Integer>
```

means "a `List` (or an instance of a subclass of `List`) that it would be acceptable to add an `Integer` to".

An `ArrayList` is a subclass of `List`; and it's entirely reasonable to add an `Integer` to an `ArrayList<Number>`, because all elements of the `ArrayList` have to be `Number`s, and `Integer` is a subclass of `Number`.

Comment: Probably worth noting that the `List` part means 'any `List`' too, and `ArrayList implements List`.  Just in case there's some additional confusion there.

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably confusing `super` with `extends`. `? super Integer` means that the generic type should be a parent for Integer or Integer itself, Number is a super (aka parent) class for Integer so the argument is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

`List<? super Integer>` means you can call the method with an argument typed as List of Integer or as a List of any supertype of Integer.

So one alternative is to give it a list of Integers:

```
ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
ints.add(new Integer(0));
numsUpTo(ints);
```

or you can call it with a list of numbers, like

```
List<Number> nums = new ArrayList<>();
nums.add(new Double(1.4));
nums.add(new Integer(3));
numsUpTo(nums);
```

or you can call it with a list of objects, like

```
List<Object> objects = new LinkedList<>();
objects.add("hello");
objects.add(new Integer(42));
objects.add(new Double(3.14));
numsUpTo(objects);
```

In all these cases it's ok for numsUpTo to add Integers to the list because Integer is always a valid element type.